# Angular. Change type of input

Tags: html, angular

I have div, that, when pressed, triggers a function that change type of input.
There are two inputs, they have 'password' type, function, changes it to 'text'

**Problem**
Error 1: 'password' is possibly 'null'.
If i put <!> to the password field, there is new error: Property 'type' does not exist on type 'Element'.

Html:

```
<div class="eyes" (click)="togglePasswords()">
    <i *ngIf="show_password" class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i *ngIf="!show_password" class="fa fa-eye-slash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

TypeScript:

```
public togglePasswords(): void {
    let password = document.querySelector(".password");
    let repeat_password = document.querySelector(".repeat-password");

    this.show_password = !this.show_password;

    if (this.show_password) {
        password.type = "text";
        repeat_password.type = "text";
    }   else {
        password.type = "password"
        repeat_password.type = "password";
    }
}
```

I repeated it with a simple site (made index.html, put there script tag, in script.js repeated this), and it worked.

I inserted js code to  tag inside html component in angular, but it didn't help.

**I solved it!**

I should have used `password.setAttribute("type", "text")` instead of `password.type = "text"`

Guy who helped me, why did you delete your answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use input element like below in angular.

```
<input [type]="show_password ? 'text' : 'password'">
```

And on click you just need to toggle show_password value.

Comment: It doesn't help. In dev tools will: type="true".

Comment: I used this in mupliple places previously and it worked for me.